# Retornar vários atributos usando XPATH

Tags: xml, xpath

Como consigo retornar vários atributos utilizando a linguagem xpath?
Por exemplo deste xml:

```
<utilizador>
        <nome>Rui</nome>
        <contacto>91xxxxxxx</contacto>
        <localidade>Viseu</localidade>
        <cesto>
            <encomenda refidprod="rlg05" estado="enviado" data="13-01-2014"/>
            <encomenda refidprod="hifi02" estado="enviado" data="1-10-2014"/>
        </cesto>
        <cestohist>
            <encomendas refidprod="tv02" estado="entregue" data="29-11-2014"/>
        </cestohist>
<utilizador>
```

Como retorno os valores dos atributos das encomendas, tanto do cestohist como cesto?

Cumpz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No exemplo do XML, seria `//utilizador/cesto | //utilizador/cestohist` para retornar qualquer um dos dois atributos.

**Explicando**: Cada um dos `//utilizador/cesto` e `//utilizador/cestohist` retornam apenas um atributo, o operador `|` é usado de forma a unir os dois resultados.

Comment: Obrigado, era mesmo isso que precisava.